Real-Time Financial Data Analysis with Python/Wolfram Language Hybrid – Overcoming Blocking Issues
Background Information:
I'm in the process of building a workflow for real-time financial data analysis using the Wolfram Language on a budget. Due to the lack of native websocket support in Mathematica, I've decided to create a hybrid system that leverages Python for real-time data acquisition and Mathematica for analysis and processing.
After exploring various options for market data (alpaca, polygon.io, Alpha Vantage, Schwab, etc.), I found that the Schwab Developer API provides the best granularity available for free, with data updates down to the second. This level of detail is crucial for my analysis needs, and it's been the most suitable option I've found without requiring expensive subscriptions.
The Challenge:
My main problem arises when integrating the real-time data feed with Mathematica. I am using SessionSubmit to run asynchronous tasks in Mathematica that receive data from Python via ZeroMQ. The data is stored in a list (dataList) as it arrives. However, when I attempt to access or display dataList in Mathematica (by typing dataList and pressing Shift+Enter), the notebook blocks and waits for the next data update from the websocket.
I want to be able to access and work with the stored data immediately, without any blocking behavior. Ideally, when I request the data, I should get the current state of dataList instantly, without waiting for the next data update.
What I’ve Tried:
I initially used CreateScheduledTask, but then switched to SessionSubmit for more flexibility. Despite this, the blocking issue persists.
I've tried using Dynamic to display dataList, but the front end still waits for the next scheduled task to execute before showing the data.
I suspect the issue may be related to how Mathematica handles the task and data synchronization, but I haven't found a way to resolve it.
My Goal:
I currently have data streaming into the WL notebook in real-time. I need a method to immediately access and display the current contents of dataList, without waiting for the next websocket activity or encountering any blocking behavior. The websocket server is written in Python with ~20 lines of code. I could post it if someone needs. Here is my Mathematica code:
subscribe = SocketConnect[{"127.0.0.1", 63217}, {"ZMQ", "SUB"}];
SetOptions[subscribe, "ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE" -> ""];
dataList = {};
receiveMessage[socket_] := Module[{msg, data},msg = SocketReadMessage[socket];
If[msg === $Failed,Nothing,data =ImportString[ByteArrayToString[msg], "JSON"];
AppendTo[dataList, data];data]];
task = SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[Module[{data},
data = receiveMessage[subscribe];
Print["Received Data: ", data];],1]];

(* asyncTask = 
CreateScheduledTask[Module[{data}, 
data = receiveMessage[subscribe]; Print[data]],1];
StartScheduledTask[asyncTask];*)

The socket is bound to the local host on port 63217 in Python. Mathematica connects to the same port and receives data continuously. The recieveMessage function converts the incoming messages to strings and appends them to dataList. When I ask for dataList, that is where a significant delay takes place. SessionSubmit completely blocks and CreateScheduledTask waits for the update.
Edit: Python to Wolfram Data Bridge
import Sconfig,schwabdev,zmq,json
from datetime import datetime
# Configuration
stock_symbol = "SPY"
current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d")

# ZeroMQ setup
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:63217")

client = schwabdev.Client(Sconfig.appKey, Sconfig.appSecret)

def my_handler(message, another_var):    

    print(message)
    socket.send_string(json.dumps(message))

# Start the data collection
streamer = client.stream
streamer.start(my_handler, "test")
streamer.send(streamer.level_one_equities(stock_symbol, 
"0,1,2,3,4,5,9"))

This program does the following

Connects to Schwab's Market Data API using the Python library(scwabdev) built by Tylere Bowers and my credentials.
Creates a local ZMQ socket connection bound to port 63217.
Sends a JSON string through the ZMQ socket every time a message is received from the market data API.

The data I'm sending in this example is for the S&P500 index "SPY" and contains the symbol, bid price, ask price, last price, bid size, ask size, and last size. This workflow will be incredibly useful if Mathematica can act on that incoming data in real-time. I am looking to fully decouple my working with dataList from the data accumulation effort.
